# Continuous extension of $f(x)=x\log(x)$: Show $\lvert f(a)-f(b)\rvert\leq\lvert f(b-a)\rvert$ for $0<a<b$ small.

Tags: analysis

I am considering the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x\log x, & x>0\\
0, & x=0\end{cases}
$$
on an interval $[0,\varepsilon]$ for small $\varepsilon>0$.

I would like to argue that for $x,y\in [0,\varepsilon]$ with $0<a<b$ one has
$$
\lvert f(a)-f(b)\rvert\leq\lvert f(b-a)\rvert.
$$

I think, in order to show this, one could use that near $x=0$ the function is convex and $f(0)=0$.

This immediately implies superadditivity, that is,
$$
f(a+b)\geq f(a)+f(b).
$$

Can one use this to prove the desired statement?

I do not see it.

Comment: I see! Then my idea is wrong. Is there another way to see the statement (or is it false)?

Comment: My previous remark was wrong. I have taken the liberty to restore your original question.

Comment: Thanks, you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea works. $f$ is convex with $f(0) = 0$ and therefore superadditive. $f$ is decreasing on $[0, 1/e]$, so that for $0 \le a < b \le 1/e$
$$
 |f(a) - f(b)| = f(a) - f(b) = f(a) - f(a+b-a) \\
\le f(a) - (f(a) + f(b-a)) = -f(b-a) 
= |f(b-a)|\, .
$$

Comment: What is $1/e$? Is this my $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @John_Doe: $e$ is the Euler number. For $x < 1/e$ is $f'(x) = \log(x) + 1 < 0$ so that $f$ is decreasing (assuming that you mean the *natural* logarithm).

Comment: I do see your point.